# What do I need to do to install a .package file?

Tags: linux, installation

I downloaded yenka last time and I don't know how to install it.
Can you advise me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you downloaded it from [here](http://www.yenka.com/en/Downloads/).

The package file is a program that you need to run.

You firstly need to make it executable; unlike Windows, Linux tends not to be all that keen on you running random programs that you have downloaded from the internet. Either right click in your file manager and change the permissions (look for something along the lines of "executable" or "allow this file to run as a program") or use the `chmod` program on the command line (`chmod a+x Yenka_3.2.6.package`).

You then need to run the program, either from your file manager again (click, double click, right click and select execute or whatever you normally do) or from the command line run `./Yenka_3.2.6.package` (change `.` to the relevant path if you are not currently in the same directory as the file).

Then you just need to follow the prompts...